# How to infer variable type at assignment instead of declaration?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

Let's say I have this declaration:

```
let spyObjs;
```

The type of `spyObjs` will be `any`. Now if I have this assignment:

```
let spyObjs = {fruit: 'apple', os: 'windows'};
```

The type of `spyObjs` will be `{fruit: string, os: string}`, because the type is inferred. What I want is this:

```
let spyObjs;
spyObjs = {fruit: 'apple', os: 'windows'};
```

and the type of `spyObjs` to be `{fruit: string, os: string}`. Unfortunately, the type is still `any`.

How can this be achieved with TS 3.0?

Cheers!

## **EDIT**

Ok, I'm sorry if the example was ambiguous. The code would look a little more like:

```
let spyObjs;

let someFunction = () => {
    spyObjs = { fruit: 'apple', os: 'windows' };
}

let someOtherFunction = () => {
    // user spyObjs here also
}

someFunction()
someOtherFunction()
```

How can the type be inferred in this scenario?

Comment: Why are you declaring without initializing? Given the code you're showing, there is no good use-case to ever write this, so it's a good idea to show what you're doing and why you think you need stricter type inference there instead of changing the code to ensure type inference is correct from the get-go.

Comment: Updated the example.

Comment: Okay but still: why would you write this, instead of having `someFunction` _return_ the data, and doing your declare-and-assign later, using `let spyObj = someFunction();`? This is still basically "bad code": there is no reason for functions to modify global variables in local scope: just return data when requested, or if the function should "enrich" an object, pass that object in as argument. Don't use global variables that can get modified as a "side effect" of calling a function: make that code intentional.

Comment: This is just an example…just imagine the code is in a closure for heaven's sake lol! This is a snippet, not production code. It’s only purpose is to illustrate the use case I’m talking about. I don't need your "good code" advice, or the question would have been totally different. If you don’t have a solution to my problem or even if you think there are no solutions, feel free to comment.

Comment: I will (for heaven's sake?) do no such thing. If you have a real problem, show an [mcve] of that problem. If you're just writing toy code, we don't need to answer this, and if you're just musing, please mention that in the post. If you have real code that runs into this problem, then _it too_ might very well have "rewrite this, to be typescript-friendly" as solution. Rather than "trying to fight typescript by doing something you wouldn't be writing in the first place". Right now, for what you show, the solution really is "just rewrite it, what you have is bad good".

Answer (score 0):

First you can't declare two variable with the same name.

let spyObjs;
let spyObjs = { fruit: 'apple', os: 'windows' };

Ts error: Can not redeclare block-scoped variable "spyObjs"

Secondly when you declare this
let spyObjs = { fruit: 'apple', os: 'windows' };
its type no longer is "any". it becomes "{ fruit: 'apple', os: 'windows' }"

Comment: I know I can't delcare two variables with the same name...they were part of two different examples. Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question. Regarding the second part of your answer, no it does not, that's my problem.